# how to delete uploaded image on asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I upload files but I don't know how to delete them:

```
            string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\userfiles\\";
            //2-get and check file etention
            string[] validExt = { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (Array.IndexOf(validExt, ext.ToLower()) < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //3-get and check file size
            long size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            size /= 1024;
            if (size > 2024)
            {

                return;
            }
            if (size == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            //4-get file name
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);


            //5-check file exsist and if (true) generate new name
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(path + "\\" + filename))
            {
                filename = "1" + filename;
            }
            //6-savefile to server
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(path + filename);
            //we can save file name in to the data base
            Session.Add("pic", "userfiles/" + filename);
```

Can u help me and say how delete images in the another page?
I save the image address in database  like userfiles/a.jpg

I can't delete images with this code:

`System.IO.File.Delete("~/" + adver.Pic);`

Comment: Please see [Writing The Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code showing that you are saving filename in Session variable. To get the filename stored in session variable use the below code -

```
System.IO.File.Delete("~/" + Session("pic"))
```

If you use Database then pls retrieve the file path from DB and then use like above [replace Session variable with file path variable.].

Comment: i do what you say but it didn't work . i use the code  "   File.Delete( adver.Pic); "  my file path is in adver.pic but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Means `adver.Pic` not containing correct file name to delete. To simplify things I'm adding another example. I think you can make changes to suite your need-

C# Code

```
private void UploadFileExample()
{
string s_FileName = null;
//Upload the file
fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/userfiles/" + fileupload1.FileName));
//Get File Name of the uploaded file
s_FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
//Now to delete the file use below code
System.IO.File.Delete("~/Uploads/userfiles/" + s_FileName);
}
```

I'm not a C# coder, I just converted above code from below VB code -

```
Private Sub UploadFileExample ()    
Dim s_FileName as String    
    fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/userfiles/" + fileupload1.FileName))    
    s_FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName)    
    System.IO.File.Delete("~/Uploads/userfiles/" + s_FileName)
End Sub
```

Let me know if you need any further help.